# phpMyAdmin's links will not function after viewing a table's structure

Tags: php, nginx, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-12.04

When any user logs into phpMyAdmin to view/edit tables, navigates to any table, and views the structure, they can no longer click on any links to navigate to any other part of phpMyAdmin until they reload the page, or open a link in a new tab / page.

The rest of the interface works without issue, as long as you do not try to view a tables structure. As soon as you view the tables structure, the links cease to work with a normal click.

I have no idea where to even begin with this one, let me know what code samples or logs would be helpful.

Configuration:

Ubuntu 12.04 (fully updated)
nginx (from Ubuntu Repo)
mysql (from Ubuntu Repo)
php5 and mysql extensions (from Ubuntu Repo)
phpMyAdmin (from GitHub Repo)

Comment: Please specify the version of phpMyAdmin. You may need to update it, or alternatively, [use one of the replacements, like adminer](http://www.adminer.org/).